# why does my program get stuck in wait(NULL)?

Tags: c, linux

I'm a c beginner and wrote a multiprocess program. I want to let my child process invoke strace and then pipe to the parent process so that parent process could print it.

But my parent progress seem to be getting stuck in `wait(NULL);` . I tried commenting code `wait(NULL);` and I got the output from my child process. I can't figure out why parent process keeping waiting. Hasn't the child process returned yet?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int pipefd[2];
  pid_t pid;
  char *exec_argv[] = { "/bin/strace", "-T", "tree", "/bin", NULL};
  char *exec_envp[] = { "PATH=/bin", NULL };

  if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
    perror("pipe");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  pid = fork();
  if (pid < 0) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else if (pid == 0) { // child
    close(pipefd[0]);   /* close unused read end */
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    if (dup2(pipefd[1], STDERR_FILENO) == -1) {
      perror("dup2");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // invoke strace
    execve(exec_argv[0], exec_argv, exec_envp);
    perror(exec_argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else {  // parent
    close(pipefd[1]);   /* close unused write end */
    if (dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1) {
      perror("dup2");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("I'm parent!!!\n");
    wait(NULL);
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len;
    while (getline(&line, &len, stdin) != -1) {
      printf("%s", line);
    }
    free(line);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close `pipefd[0]` in the parent.

You didn't close `pipefd[1]` in the child.

---

Another problem is that your code is susceptible to deadlocks. If the child writes enough to the pipe to fill it, it will block until it has space to accept more. And since the the pipe is not emptied until the child exits, the child will never unblock.

This is easy to fix: Read until EOF, *then* call `wait` to reap the child. In other words, move the `wait` so it's after the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your question. I have found the document https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html#:~:text=If%20a%20process%20attempts%20to%20read%20from%20an%20empty%20pipe%2C%20then%20read(2)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20will%20block%20until%20data%20is%20available. So I think the wait(NULL); is needless because parent process will be blocked until child process output.

Comment: I still have a question: my child  process use execve and execve wouldn't return, so where should I close pidpefd[1]?

Comment: Yes, you could remove the wait entirely. When a program exits, that doesn't stop the process from existing. In unix systems, `wait` is what causes the process to get "reaped" (removed from the system).  If the child exits first, the child process will stick around as a zombie until the parent exits when it will be reaped automatically. If the parent exits first, the child will be reaped automatically when it completes.

Comment: Before calling `exec`, obviously.